# Flowplayer Fullscreen Doesn't shows vast ads

Tags: jquery, flash, video, flowplayer

Hi i was Developing A Flowplayer Plugin since most of plugin available around are very expensive.  I have done with IMA integration and ads running from a vast url smoothly

1. Now,  when i go to fullscreen the ads are not showing it runs on background .
2. I have used google html5 + vast functions  so when i click on a button ad passes through flowplayer..  It needs to be changed ( play button function needs to be  applied to flowplayer default play pause method)

Comment: Can you show relevant code?

Comment: you can check the code here http://flowplayer.weibsites.com/google/google/

there is two player 

 need to add vast url from sample tag and

 then need to click play button on first player 

Ad will be played on flowplayer